# Can my laptop become infected thru work pc wireless internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking

can i use my laptop safely by connecting wireless to my work pc. it is not a network.  Im trying to save $50 mo.  on my internet fees. Since i have pc at work, I only use laptop for bill paying and news.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what your concern is. Infections come from things like web sites, email attachments, and being connected to an infected computer.  Whether the connection uses a cable or a wireless connection doesn't make any difference.  If the work PC is clean, that wouldn't be a source.  You say it's not on a network, but you need a path to the Internet for the activity you mention.  It's the Internet, itself, that's the potential source, rather than how you connect to it.  Regardless of how you get there, you want an active anti-virus program running in the background on your laptop.

Comment: I think another issue you may not have considered is your company's policy on connecting personal devices to the corporate network.

Answer (score 1):

Any device connected to the internet can be infected if not used carefully.

When you browse the internet, a bannerclick or malicious script can cause a virus or spyware to be installed on your computer. Receiving an email with a malicious attachment and you opening that attachment is also a way to get infected.

If you open files from your laptop that reside on your work pc or otherwise on the network and that file is somehow infected, that too can cause for problems.

If you have files shared on your laptop and your work pc has shares open, an infection can access files on your laptop and infect them (think of crypto virusses, a threat that is becoming more active nowadays).